# Is IT possible with EJS cli to process the whole directory recursively?

Tags: javascript, ejs

As I see currently, [it's not possible to run the EJS CLI against a whole directory](https://github.com/mde/ejs?tab=readme-ov-file#cli), i.e.

```bash
ejs my-template output
```

where:

- my-template - is a project with placeholders
- output - the target output directory where all the files will be located

Is there any fork/opensource project to run against the whole project?

I want to have a directory with many files and many EJS-styled placeholders to be generated into a given directory. I can write a custom code but I wonder about something ready

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be solved by simple Javascript code.

I wrote the sample code here

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const ejs = require('ejs');

const inputDir = 'my-template';
const outputDir = 'output';

function processDirectory(directory) {
  const files = fs.readdirSync(directory);

  files.forEach((file) => {
    const filePath = path.join(directory, file);
    const stats = fs.statSync(filePath);

    if (stats.isDirectory()) {
      processDirectory(filePath);
    } else {
      const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
      const renderedContent = ejs.render(fileContent, { /* your data */ });
      const outputPath = path.join(outputDir, file);

      fs.writeFileSync(outputPath, renderedContent);
    }
  });
}

processDirectory(inputDir);
```

Here, you have to provide necessary data to each file.
I think you can make a Json file that store the total input data  And use it.

I hope this code will help you.

Comment: thanks, I will use this if no further findings